# Laravel, Get data about products of order

Tags: laravel

I have a page with list of orders.
And each order have a number of products. Like this

order id | 
email                    | 
list of products                            | 
status

1 | 
client@site.com   | 
product 1 ($5), product 2 ($10)   | 
done

2 | 
client2@site.com | 
product 2 ($10), product 3 ($15) | 
done

Please see database structure
[db_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQkne.png)

How I can show in blade list of products? Quantity of orders can be about 100.
I know about joins, relations (may be hasMany()) and load/with.

Answer (score 0):

use this will work

```
DB::table('order_product')
->join('products','products.id','=','order_product.product_id')
->join('orders','orders.id','=','order_product.order_id')
->select('order_product.order_id','orders.client_email.','products.name','order_product.quantity','products.price')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Good. What do you think, if I have
product_1, $5, 2 items
product_2, $10, 3 items

And I need show
product 1, $5 * 2
product 2, $10 * 3